# Retrieve all the attributes for an entity

Tags: vaticle-typeql

I am trying to figure out a Graql code. where I need to list all the attributes for an entity. Please suggest.

I need to list all the attributes of an entity.
for ex: a person has age, gender, and height. I need to get o/p as age, gender, and height.

Answer (score 2):

In general on any Concept you get back from a Graql query you can use the `.attributes()` method and then on every attribute you can use `.value()` and `.type().label()` to see what type of attribute you're handling, example:

sudo code (as I don't know which language you want to use)

```
var attributes = person.attributes();
for(attribute in attributes){
   print("Attribute "+attribute.type().label()+ "with value: "+ attribute.value())
}
```

Please check official documentation fro Concept API: https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/concept-api/thing

Some examples:
https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/examples/phone-calls-queries
and the blog with many examples: https://blog.grakn.ai/

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options if you use Graql to ask for the owned attributes directly.

Firstly, to ask for all owned attributes, you can do this:

```
match $p isa person, has attribute $a; get $a;
```

Now you will get back the attributes `$p` owns as `$a`. You will see the types of those attributes when viewed in the Grakn console. Using a Grakn client for Python/Node.js/Java etc. you need to then use `concept.type().label()` on each Concept that you get back in order to find out their types.

Alternatively, you can find the owned attributes and their types directly using:

```
match $p isa person, has attribute $a; $a isa! $t; get $a, $t;
```

This also queries for the type of `$a`, giving that type as `$t`. You notice here that this is exactly the same as a normal statement, but we have replaced declaring a specific type with a variable.

In this query, the `!` of `isa!` is important here. When using `isa`, `$t` will yield the type of `$a` and all of its super types as well.

Instead, using `isa!` asks for only the direct type, so you will get only the actual type of the attribute back, not the super types, which means you most likely want to use `isa!`.